# PHP, how to pass func-get-args values to another function as list of arguments?

Tags: php

I want to create a function (`my_function()`) getting unlimited number of arguments and passing it into another function (`call_another_function()`).

```
function my_function() {    
   another_function($arg1, $arg2, $arg3 ... $argN);    
}
```

So, want to call `my_function(1,2,3,4,5)` and get calling `another_function(1,2,3,4,5)`

I know that I shoud use `func_get_args()` to get all function arguments as array, but I don't know how to pass this arguments to another function.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you modify another_function to accept an array as parameter?

Comment: Nope, it's third party function :(

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
function my_function() {    
    $args = func_get_args();
    call_user_func_array("another_function", $args);
}
```

In programming and computer science, this is called an [apply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apply) function.

Comment: Beware though, func_get_args cannot be used as parameter to another function! You need a temporary variable to capture the arguments first.

Comment: @Jordan, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979507/difference-in-behaviour-of-func-num-args-func-get-arg-and-func-get-args-from-php

Comment: To sum it up, the temporary variable was only needed for PHP < 5.2.

Comment: The callback seems to be interpreted eval-alike and `call_user_func_array` also returns the callback's result. `$ret_value = call_user_func_array("MyClass::my_method", $args);` works.

Answer (score 11):

Use `call_user_func_array`
like

```
call_user_func_array('another_function', func_get_args());
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not yet documented but you might use [reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) API, especially invokeArgs.

(maybe I should have used a comment rather than a full post)

Comment: I've checked reflection API, but my OOP PHP is too poor to understand practical side of "reflection API". :(

Comment: Here is the nice url http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/16/4/0 that helped me to understand Reflection class.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved such a problem with the `...$args` parameter in the function.

In my case, it was arguments forwarding to the parent construction call.

```
public function __construct(...$args)
{
    parent::__construct(...$args);
}
```