# Difference in behaviour of func_num_args,func_get_arg and func_get_args from php 5.2 to 5.3

Tags: php

I have seen the PHP manual. But I don't understand the difference in behaviour between the earlier version and the later versions of PHP. I don't understand this statement:

> Because this function depends on the current scope to determine parameter details, it cannot be used as a function parameter in versions prior to 5.3.0. If this value must be passed, the results should be assigned to a variable, and that variable should be passed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you wanted to pass the result of one of those functions to another function or a method, in versions of PHP prior to 5.3 you had to first assign the result to a variable.

```
function some_func() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    some_other_func($args);
}
```

This limitation was removed in PHP 5.3 and you can now pass the result directly.

```
function some_func() {
    some_other_func(func_get_args());
}
```

As to why this limitation existed in the first place, perhaps someone with a more thorough understanding of PHP's internals can give you a more complete answer.

Comment: It probably has something to do with PHP getting really confused between the scope of the calling function and the function it's being passed to.

Comment: It seemed to work OK in some really strange scenarios too: http://codepad.org/MQkQnnJH

Answer (score 8):

It means that this is invalid in 5.2:

```
function foo() {
    $array = array_map('strtolower', func_get_args());
}
foo('BAR', 'BAZ');
```

It will abort with a Fatal error:

> PHP Fatal error:  func_get_args(): Can't be used as a function parameter

However in 5.3, it is valid code.