# What is the difference between func_get_arg() and

Tags: php, function, arguments

What is the difference between these two code excerpts, respectively, in PHP?:

```
function eat_apple($apple)
{
    return true;
}
```

And:

```
function eat_apple()
{
    $apple = func_get_arg(0);
    return true;
}
```

Or is there a difference? If there is not, what is the point of func_get_arg()? Surely it serves some purpose I'm not aware of?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference in behaviour of func_num_args,func_get_arg and func_get_args from php 5.2 to 5.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979507/difference-in-behaviour-of-func-num-args-func-get-arg-and-func-get-args-from-php)

Comment: That is related to differences between different versions of the func_get_arg() series of functions. It does not apply to my question.

Comment: Isnt it obvious by looking at the function signature already? The first is telling the truth. The other is lieing. Apart from that, the reason for using `func_get_arg` is given in the [PHP Manual, which you are supposed to check before asking questions](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php): *allow user-defined functions to accept variable-length argument lists. *

Answer (score 7):

[`func_get_arg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php) (and [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)) make it possible to have functions with a **variable number of parameters**, so called [***variadic functions***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

Take [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) as an example, which takes a variable number of arrays to be merged.

Comment: Ah. So if there are more than one argument passed, func_get_arg will have to be used?

Comment: Not necessarily, because you can also define a function with arguments with default values, which also allows you to have a variable number of arguments.

Comment: @Kobie: No, if your function takes two parameters, you can define it as `function foo($a, $b)`. I mean if the function takes a variable number of parameters, where the number of parameters is not known at "compile time".

Comment: @Felix - still not necessarily: if you didn't know that `$a` or `$b` are going to be passed, you could define defaults for them and still define them as normal: `function($a=NULL, $b=NULL)`. `func_get_args()` only *really* needs to come into play if you're thinking in terms of an unlimited number of arguments, as per `printf()`.

Answer (score 1):

In truth, there isn't much difference, and a standard passed argument is usually preferable over `func_get_arg()`.

There are two occasions when you might want to use `func_get_arg()` rather than using defined arguments:

1. If you want to have an unlimited number of arguments. Typically, this would be better done with a single array argument, but there are times when you may want to allow unlimited arguments. A real example of a function that works this way is PHP's built-in `printf` function.
2. Where you have a complex function where the number of arguments given may alter what the arguments are used for and/or their data type. For example, passing a single argument may cause the function to expect a string, whereas passing two arguments, it may expect an integer first, and then the string. I can't think of any examples of this off the top of my head, but I'm fairly sure there are some. Ordinarily, I would say that this sort of behaviour is bad practice, but I can see how it may be useful for adding features while maintaining backward compatibility.

There are two things that you will definitely lose if you use `fung_get_arg()` instead of standard function arguments:

1. The ability to pass by reference.
2. The ability for your IDE to do any type hinting or auto-completion.

Answer (score 1):

> Hello. What is the difference between these two code excerpts, respectively, in PHP?:

```
-function eat_apple($apple)
+function eat_apple()
 {
+    $apple = func_get_arg(0);
     return true;
 }
```

---

> what is the point of func_get_arg()? Surely it serves some purpose I'm not aware of?

The officially stated purpose is to:

> Return an item from the argument list
>
> -- http://php.net/func-get-arg

Answer (score 0):

The other possible reason I could think of is avoiding a fatal error.

You have a function:

```
<?php
function display ($a, $b, $c) {
    echo $a . " is " . $b . " " . $c;
}
?>
```

and you could call

```
<?php
display ("Rock", "good", "boy");
- this will not throw any error.

display ("Rock", "good");
- this will throw fatal error.
?>
```

So, now think of the second call, you could avoid the fatal error, see how many arguments are passed with `func_get_args` and process your code with `func_get_arg(1)` etc.

Comment: this doesn't require `func_get_args()`, because you can define defaults for arguments: `function disaply($a='', $b='', $c='')`. Will not throw an error if you only pass one or two arguments.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but for those who don't use default it helps. Agree?

Comment: If you didn't want to use defaults, then yes it would help. But why wouldn't you use defaults? The only reason I can think of is if you intend to allow an unknown number of arguments, but reasons for doing that are few and far between.

Comment: Oh yes, the first possible reason.

Answer (score 0):

### Several reasons:

1. You can use that magic to emulate overloading
2. You can write function (like `printf`) which can take undetermined number of arguments.

### Example for first:

```
class a{
  function X(MyOBJ $obj){...}
}

class b extends a{
  function X(string $s,int $i){...}
}
class c extends b{
  function X(){...}
}
```

This will throw a warning. If you use `func_get_args()` inside the function to get relevant parameters, no warning will be thrown.

### Example for the second:

```
//not good, you can only send 3 strings
function merge_strings($s1, $s2, $s3){
     return $s1 . $s2 . $s3;
}

//good one
function merge_strings(){
   return join('',func_get_args());
}
```