# Can a method with an unknown number of arguments call another method with an unknown number of arguments?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP, how to pass func-get-args values to another function as list of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126778/php-how-to-pass-func-get-args-values-to-another-function-as-list-of-arguments)

I have a method in a base class that can take any number of arguments. This method needs to call a method of a third-party object which can take any number of arguments using those passed to the first method.

I mention that it is a third-party object that is to be called to reinforce the constraint that the called method's signature cannot be modified to accept an array or object.

Example:

```
<?php
class Example {     

    private $thirdPartyObject = null;

    public function methodOne() {
        $arguments = func_get_args();

        $this->thirdPartyObject = new ThirdPartyObject();
        $this->externalObject->methodName(/* pass on variable number of arguments here */);
    }
}

$exampleObject = new Example();
$exampleObject->methodOne('a', 'b', 'c');
```

If we know in advance the number of arguments being passed to `Example->methodOne()` we could then pass on the same number of arguments to `ThirdPartyObject->methodName()`.

If we do not know in advance the number of arguments being passed to `Example->methodOne()`, can we pass these arguments on to `ThirdPartyObject->methodName()`?

In this case, `ThirdPartyObject->methodName()` is called with one or more arguments such as:

```
<?php
$thirdPartyObject = new ThirdPartyObject();
$thirdPartyObject->methodName('a');
$thirdPartyObject->methodName('a', 'b');
$thirdPartyObject->methodName('a', /* ... */, 'N');
```

Comment: Have you tried this?: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126778/php-how-to-pass-func-get-args-values-to-another-function-as-list-of-arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126778/php-how-to-pass-func-get-args-values-to-another-function-as-list-of-arguments)

Comment: @des: thanks for the suggestion, my searches didn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/call_user_func_array)(), i think. But using it is not a good practice. It is quite slow.

```
call_user_func_array(array($this->externalObject, "methodName"), $arguments);
```

Comment: If using an opcode cache such as APC, are such performance concerns of lesser significance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array), like so:

```
$this->thirdPartyObject = new ThirdPartyObject();
call_user_func_array( array( $this->externalObject, 'methodName'),  $arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`call_user_func_array`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)**.

However, you should simply pass the array of arguments (`$arguments`) and utilize that in your other method.

Comment: " you should simply pass the array of arguments" - the other method is of a third party object, it does not take an array of arguments and I cannot change this,

Comment: @JonCram: Consider my second part of the answer useless in which case. I will leave it for future reference in case another user has the same problem, only he can change the structure of his code.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use class Example extends ThirdPartyObject then set a default value for the variable that you want to pass.

Comment: In this specific case, Example is a Symfony2 entity and ThirdPartyObject is Doctrine EntityRepository. That can't work.